# Zivnostensky visa travel restrictions in Czech Republic

Tags: visa, czech-republic

Does anyone know if there are travel restrictions for someone who has applied for a trades license in CZ, but not yet received it?

I was told I could not travel into or out of the Czech republic while awaiting approval, but I have a D/VC/06 stamp issued 2017.

Comment: Who told you cannot travel? The embassy? An Internet forum? Also, why do you need a trade license? Most one-man activities don't need one.

Comment: The woman who has been assisting me in getting a Zivnostensky list visa since I arrived in CZ to get a TEFL certificate told me I could not travel.  I was told the only way I could teach in CZ was with a Zivno.  Please advise.

Comment: So you are inside the Czech Republic? How long have you stayed here and what's your citizenship?

Comment: And did you already apply for a long-term residency? Because a D/VC/06 stamp is a short-term business visa.